# Set access policy for Bigquery policy tag

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am looking for a python API to set the access policy for a policy tag inside a bigquery taxonomy in gcp.

I have gone through [this](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/write-policy-client-libraries) page in gcp documentation, and while it works, it only talks about getting or setting IAM policy at project level.

If I change the resource in above code example to something like 
"projects/my-project-1/location/us-east1/taxonomies/taxonomy_1/policyTags/first_tag" 
or
 "projects/my-project-1/bigquery/policy-tags/locations/us-east1/taxonomies/taxonomy_1/policyTags/first_tag" 
it fails with bellow error

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projects%2Fsilly-tomato-386917%2Flocation%2Fus-east1%2Ftaxonomies%2Ftaxonomy_1%2FpolicyTags%2Ffirst_tag:getIamPolicy?alt=json returned "Request contains an invalid argument.". Details: "Request contains an invalid argument.">
```

I am guessing that could also be because the `/` are  getting changed to `%2F`, but I don't know how to tell the `setIamPolicy` to stop doing that, or that's even possible for that matter

Point is, has anyone successfully set IAM policy or access control to GCP's bigquery policy tags (BigQuery -> Policy tags -> Taxonomy -> Policy tags) using Python?

Is that even possible via any gcp python api as of today?

Posting the code that I have right now below

Check `modify_policy_add_role1` to see what works and what doesnt.

Eventually the goal is to set IAM policy for Bigquery Policy tag access, however at this point I am struggling to make `getIamPolicy()` work for a policy tag

```
import google.auth
import googleapiclient.discovery
from googleapiclient import discovery
from google.oauth2 import service_account   


def quickstart(project_id: str, member: str) -> None:
    """Gets a policy, adds a member, prints their permissions, and removes the member."""

    # Role to be granted.
    role = "roles/logging.logWriter"

    # Initializes service.
    crm_service = initialize_service()

    # Grants your member the 'Log Writer' role for the project.
    modify_policy_add_role1(crm_service, project_id, role, member)


def initialize_service() -> dict:
    """Initializes a Cloud Resource Manager service."""

    #credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
    #    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    #)

    scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']
    sa_file = './silly-tomato-386917-4035a1d05cf8.json'
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(sa_file, scopes=scopes)
    crm_service = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        "cloudresourcemanager", "v1", credentials=credentials
    )
    return crm_service


def modify_policy_add_role1(
    crm_service: str, project_id: str, role: str, member: str
) -> None:
    """Adds a new role binding to a policy."""

    #policy = "{'version': 1,'etag': 'BwX+jREol0k=','bindings': [{'role': 'roles/owner', 'members':['serviceAccount:kaway-568@silly-tomato-386917.iam.gserviceaccount.com','serviceAccount:kawayadmin@silly-tomato-386917.iam.gserviceaccount.com', 'user:arnabbhagabati1@gmail.com']}]}"   

    #This works
    #rname = f"{project_id}"
    
    #This works too
    rname = 'silly-tomato-386917'
    
    #this does not work
    #rname = 'silly-tomato-386917/bigquery/policy-tags/locations/us-east1/taxonomies/taxonomy_1/policyTags/first_tag'
    
    policy = get_policy(crm_service, rname)
    print(policy)

    #newPolicy=set_policy(crm_service, res, policy) 
    #print(newPolicy)    


def get_policy(crm_service: str, res_str: str, version: int = 3) -> dict:
    """Gets IAM policy for a project."""

    policy = (
        crm_service.projects()
        .getIamPolicy(
            resource=res_str,
            body={"options": {"requestedPolicyVersion": version}},
        )
        .execute()
    )
    return policy


def set_policy(crm_service: str, project_id: str, policy: str) -> dict:
    """Sets IAM policy for a project."""

    policy = (
        crm_service.projects()
        .setIamPolicy(resource=project_id, body={"policy": policy})
        .execute()
    )
    return policy


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # TODO: replace with your project ID
    project_id = "silly-tomato-386917"
    # TODO: Replace with the ID of your member in the form 'user:member@example.com'.
    member = "user:someEmail@gmail.com"
    quickstart(project_id, member)
```

Comment: I didn't catch your test. Why did you delete the taxonomy and the tags from the URL? It's normal it fails if you break the expected resource pattern format!

Comment: I didnt, it was just an example. Updated question to make it more clear

Comment: Do you have a piece of code to let us try and reproduce the issue?

Comment: Added the code that I have right now